# CSS Selector for child input

Tags: css

I am trying to create a CSS selector so I can set a background for the input control.  I only have access to the myautocomplete class in css.

[image]

I have tried the following but can't seem to style the input.

```
.myautocomplete input {
    background-color: Red;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px orange;
    }
```

I have also tried:

```
.myautocomplete  > input {
  background-color: Red;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px orange;
}
```

Comment: The first CSS selector, so it's something else. Can you post the actual rendered HTML so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: The second selector will not work as the input is not a child of `.myautocomplete`.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS applies on every child/subchild inputs of `.myautocomplete`

```
.myautocomplete input {
    background-color: red;
}
```